# How to specify custom layout for a DropdownPreference?

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I want to use a custom layout for a DropDownPreference.

When I specify the layout as an android:layout="@layout/mylayout", I get a runtime error. Can anyone confirm if they have done this previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

The issue was that I was not implementing Spinner component inside my custom Layout and DropDownPreference uses a Spinner component internally.